# Sublists in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I want to have sublists in my CV, like so:

[image]

possibly with more than one item. For instance, the first line being the thesis title and the second line the supervisor and its name. Suggestions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle{classic}                    
\moderncvcolor{blue}                              
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{2011--2014}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much else to go by, perhaps the following suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\let\oldcventry\cventry
\renewcommand{\cventry}{\par\addvspace{.5em}\oldcventry}
\newcommand{\cvsublistentry}[3][.25em]{%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  {\footnotesize\qquad\makebox[5em][r]{#2:} #3}\par}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2014}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cvsublistentry{Supervisor}{Prof.\ Who Cares}
\cvsublistentry{Examiner}{Dr.\ Cares Somewhat}

%\medskip% Maybe add some more space here...

\cventry{2015--}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cvsublistentry{Supervisor}{Prof.\ Who Cares}
\cvsublistentry{Examiner}{Dr.\ Cares Somewhat}

\end{document}
```

`\cvsublistentry` uses some of the same techniques employed by `\cventry` (copied from there), with the added font/vertical spacing changes.

Depending on your usage, additional vertical spacing may be required if you don't like the gap between a `\cvsublistentry` and a subsequent `\cventry`.

Comment: Thanks. I need the words supervisor and examiner to be right-aligned though,and the ensuing Prof. and Dr. to be left-aligned. Also, I think it'd look a little nicer if slightly smaller fonts were used for sublists.

Comment: @StefanosAivazidis: See the updated answer. I've used `\footnotesize`, but you can adjust that. Same goes for virtually everything I added. :)

Comment: Thank you. Can I control the space between supervisor and the name?

Comment: @StefanosAivazidis: Of course. In my definition I've used `\makebox[.][.]{#2:} #3` which leaves a regular inter-word space between `:` and `#3`. You can change this to (say) `\makebox[.][.]{#2:}\hspace{<len>}#3` where you supply `<len>`. `<len>`=`1em` is similar to `\quad`; `<len>`=`2em` is similar to `\qquad`. Otherwise you can specify what you want (even negative).

Comment: Ok, one last thing and I'll shut up :) Can I control the vertical space between consecutive subentries as well as between description and first entry? The vertical space between Description and Supervisor, and Supervisor and Examiner should be slightly smaller, I think.

Comment: @StefanosAivazidis: I've added some more detail in that regard. Let me know if it doesn't suit you. Note also the change to `\cventry` that I've introduced.

Comment: @Werner For a default `moderncv` banking template, how can I add multiple supervisors to be left aligned below each other?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Use `\cvitem{supervisors}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Supervisor A \\ Supervisor B \end{tabular}}`; [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngfh2.png).